# Sinch Android Messaging Tutorial App crashes upon login and client isn't started

Tags: android, messaging, sinch

The android tutorial app keeps crashing once a user has been logged in. Client also doesn't start.

Logcat Says

```
08-03 12:45:16.183    1322-1322/com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton W/linker﹕ libhoudini.so has  
text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
08-03 12:45:16.655    1322-1322/com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 
(SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 1322 (utorialskeleton)
```

This occurs when using a Genymotion emulator.

When using the standard android virtual device, the logcat reads:

```
08-03 08:45:00.705    2406-2406/com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
 EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton, PID: 2406
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sinch-android-rtc from loader 
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-
lib/com.example.messagingtutorialskeleton-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.natives.jni.UserAgentFactory.<clinit>
(UserAgentFactory.java:9)
        at 
com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.ServiceFactory.createUserAgent(ServiceFactory.java:43)
        at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.DefaultSinchClient.<init>
(DefaultSinchClient.java:144)
      at       
com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.InternalSinchClientFactory.createSinchClient(InternalSinchClie     ntFactory.java:13)
        at 
 com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder.build(DefaultSinchClientBuilder.java:95)
        at 
 com.sinch.messagingtutorialskeleton.MessageService.startSinchClient(MessageService.java:58)
        at 
 com.sinch.messagingtutorialskeleton.MessageService.onStartCommand(MessageService.java:42)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2702)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Whats the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yup i got the fix!...you just need to store all your Sinch architecture files into jniLibs folder as indicated in the tutorial.
The folder hence will include three folders which come along with the SDK namely;
1. Armeabi
2  Armeabi-v7a
3. X86

The error that you're getting is due to the missing x86 folder. Hence Do the needful and if you get stuck then please ask!

Answer (score 0):

The Sinch SDK isn't tested on the Genymotion emulator because it doesn't yet support x86. Here is a full explanation: https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial/issues/1#issuecomment-50063315

Have you tried testing the app on a physical device?

Comment: A physical device does not fix his problem, he posted his LogCat from a physical device.

Comment: No, he posted his logcats from a genymotion emulator and an android virtual device.

Comment: Did you read below the line that says " When using the standard android virtual device, the logcat reads: " That is the exact same as what you get on a physical device. Source: Did this myself.

Comment: This issue was resolved here: https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial/issues/2

Comment: Not really, the person in the thread said the problem was coming from genymotion, but the second logcat he is getting is exactly the same as what is happening on my physical device.

Comment: Did you run it on a Genymotion emulator before you tried a physical device?

Comment: Only a physical device, remember I only got the bottom portion of OP's Logcat not the top.